# Передача в функцию произвольное количество элементов произвольного типа

Tags: c++, c++14

Есть приложение, в котором при возникновениях отклонений от каких-то параметров необходимо сообщать (вызывать метод) специальному модулю место где возникло отклонение и значения некоторых переменных. Количество и типы этих переменных заранее неизвестно и меняется от случая к случаю. Различных случаев очень много. Вопрос такой, есть в std или boost какой-нибудь контейнер, через который можно передать произвольное количество элементов произвольного типа в функцию?

```
def Foo(container):
    for c in container: print(c)

A = ["Text", 14, 99.0004]
Foo (A)
```

Написал пример на python. Мне нужно сделать что-то подобное на С++ желательно не городя опять огороды.

Comment: `Foo(...)` и передавайте, что хотите :)

Comment: @Harry ушёл читать про функции с переменным числом аргументов. Спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: @mrFieldy `Foo(...)` вовсе не разрешает передавать что угодно. [Использовать функции с переменным числом параметров вообще не следует](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f55-dont-use-va_arg-arguments), так как они не являются типобезопасными. А если хочется передавать что угодно в любых количествах, то используйте `vector<boost::any>`. Но в контексте такого вопроса откровенно непонятно, зачем вам вообще С++ если вы пытаетесь впихнуть динамическую типизацию.

Comment: Есть ещё variadic template. Но код на нем писать для любителей и ценителей

Comment: @VTT я очень люблю С++ =).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все же мне кажется, что пожалуй, ближе всего к тому, что вы хотите - вариативные шаблоны:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void Foo() {}

template<typename T, typename ...Types>
void Foo(T a, Types... Args)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    Foo(Args...);
}


int main()
{
    Foo("Hello", 3.14, 824, 'a');
}
```

Comment: Вы решили мою проблему. Спасибо.

Comment: Да не за что, обращайтесь :)

Answer (score 0):

Я сейчас пробую все три способа (Foo(...), vector и variadic template). Первый и правда какая то очень небезопасная байда. Дальше всех пока продвинулся в vector но при приведении cout << boost::any_cast<…>(c) не знаю что делать что бы не писать огромный swich.

```
using boost::any;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

void Foo(vector<any>& container) {
    for (auto &c : container) {
        if (c.type() == typeid(int)) cout << boost::any_cast<int>(c) << endl;
        if (c.type() == typeid(double)) cout << boost::any_cast<double>(c) << endl;
        if (c.type() == typeid(char*)) cout << boost::any_cast<char*>(c) << endl;
        if (c.type() == typeid(std::string)) cout << boost::any_cast<std::string>(c) << endl;
    }
};

void main()
{
    vector<any> container;
    container.push_back(string("Text"));
    container.push_back(14);
    container.push_back(99.0004);

    //cout << typeid("Text").name();
    container.push_back("Text"); // Этот вариант не срабатывает, как быть с типом char[5] ?

    Foo(container);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Но текущий вариант выглядит уже не плохо, большое спасибо @VTT за подсказку.